# VAdd Fade Effect When Word is Change

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Before jumping to question, I want to say something. Actually, I'm using nuxt-3 and I didn't find any nuxt-3 compatible library.

**Question**

How to add fade effect when the word is change?

Here's the implementation on [Google Careers Website](https://careers.google.com/). On Google Career Site the word slide a little bit, but I want the simple fade effect.

Here's my implementation and In my implementation the word is changed in every 2 second and I just want to add fade effect when word is changes.

```html
<template>
<h2 class="text-red-primary text-h-2xl text-center">
  {{ greeting }}
</h2>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {onMounted, ref} from 'vue'

let greeting = ref('hello,')

let data = ['hello,', 'hola,', 'bonjour,', 'salve,', 'asalaam alaikum,']

function changeWord() {
    let counter = 0
    setInterval(()=> {
        counter++
        if (counter >= data.length) counter = 0
        greeting.value = data[counter]
    }, 2000)
}

onMounted(()=> {
    changeWord()
})

</script>
```

Comment: That one could probably be solved with a few lines of CSS. No need to have a Nuxt3 module of any sort.

Comment: @kissu I tried to add transition property but nothing happen. Can you show me how to do it by sharing some fiddle it would be appreciated.